# Preventing User from accessing login page while signed in using Flask-Login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

In Flask, one can use the `@login_required` decorator in order to protect endpoints. However, I am encountering the opposite issue - how can I prevent my login page from being accessed whilst the user is signed in?

There isn't code that I can really attach, since I have no idea where to even start on this. Any help would be much appreciated! I have followed this tutorial so my code is very similar to this:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-authentication-to-your-app-with-flask-login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit the parameters and:

```
def login_not_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if "logged_in" in session:
            return redirect(url_for("index"))
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

Answer (score 2):

Import `current_user` from `flask_login` and check if the user (`current_user`) is authenticated in your view (login view). If the user is authenticated, redirect it to the URL you want.

```
from flask_login import current_user

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Answer (score 0):

*how can I prevent my login page from being accessed whilst the user is signed in?*

You might use [flask-login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) `get_id()` and then check if what was returned `is not None`, which will mean user is logged in.